# Computability & complexity application

Tags: metaprogramming, complexity-theory, computability

I'm thinking of developing an application that deals with computability and complexity.
Its initial list of features would be:

1. Receiving a function and checking if it is computable (i.e. whether it belongs to R,RE,coRE).
2. Receiving a computable function and checking to which complexity class it belongs.

And few more,this is more or less the direction.
Are you familiar with any application like this?
If so, what are this program's features, where can I find it and can you think of a new feature that is missing from this program or not working well?

Comment: what? What exactly do you mean by compatibility (or comabitly) and complexity?

Comment: @jalf: I think it should be "combability", non? Like, "comb the desert"?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no program that does this since what you want the program to check is undecidable. The easiest part to proof undecidable is checking whether a function is in R:

If you could decide whether a function was in R or not, you could also easily decide the Halting Problem (a function `f` halts on the input `x` if and only if the function `f'`, which works the same as `f` except it hardcodes the input `x` and ignores its actual argument, is in R), which of course you can't.

Comment: Isn't it possible by reduction  & Rice sentence that function isn't belong to R/Re?

Comment: @Inbalta: I have a hard time understanding your questions, but after thinking for 10 minutes, I've concluded your comment is supposed to ask the following question: "Isn't it possible using reduction and/or Rice's theorem to decide whether a function is in R or RE or not?" Sure that's possible to do for a human, but it's definitely not possible for a computer. As a matter of fact it would be a direct contradiction of Rice's theorem if it were possible (R and RE obviously being non-trivial (same goes for co-RE and the various complexity classes)).

Comment: @sepp2k *"a function f halts on the input x if and only if the function f', which works the same as f except it hardcodes the input x and ignores its actual argument"* I think this sentence is incomplete, what can you say about `f` when looking at `f'`?

Comment: @geceo You're right the sentence was incomplete. That's fixed now. `f(x)` halts iff `f'` is in R.

Comment: For people wondering what a "function in R" means, Wikipedia has articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28complexity%29 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_%28complexity%29